# Parse date from a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

How can I convert from a non string to a date in js?

```
var date = 23/01/2016;
var parsedDate = Date.parse(date);
```

Comment: What do you mean by non string?  What kind of value type do you expect from `var date = 23/01/2016`?

Comment: Are you using nodejs with ejs? otherwise there is no way to get that value without error

Comment: Your first line is actually doing this:

    `var date = 23/1/2016; // which equals 0.011408730158730158...`

It has to be wrapped in quotes, otherwise you're simply doing the math operation divide twice on the numbers provided.